# Hot-deploying a custom .jar theme to Keycloak v21

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to deploy a custom theme to keycloak, however I am unable to get it to work the way I would like with a jar file.

Originally I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/extend-account-console

Which bascally says:

1. Create a jar with the theme
2. Drop it in `/opt/keycloak/standalone/deployments`

It seem on newer versions, `/opt/keycloak/providers` has taken over as the standard location for jar files, and these can be deployed by running `/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build`, however in order to get this to work, I need to restart the server.

We are trying to deploy this inside of a k8s cluster, and restarting the server is really not an ideal solution. Is there any way to get the theme to show up without having to use the `themes` directory, or restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#creating-a-theme

> Procedure
> Run Keycloak with the following options:

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --spi-theme-static-max-age=-1 --spi-theme-cache-themes=false --spi-theme-cache-templates=false
```

Use the command to see the effect of the customised theme without having to restart